# Ajax call not hitting Server Side method in .Net Web Forms App

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have a web forms app in which an ajax call is being made via clicking a button:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'Forum.aspx/TestMethod',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
    }
});
```

...to this Method in my Forum.aspx.cs file:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void TestMethod()
{
    Debug.Print("Hello");   
}
```

When I click the button, I get an alert that says "SUCCESS,"  But, it's not hitting the method.  I've stripped everything down to what you see above, and I'm not seeing "Hello" in VS' Output window (nor is it hitting any breakpoints I set).  I *do* have a line in my `Page_Load` method that says `Debug.Print("LOAD")`, and when I click the button, I do get "LOAD" in the Output window.  So, it's hitting the `Page_Load` method, but not the `TestMethod` I actually need it to call.

Can anyone think of ANYTHING that might be wrong???

Comment: If you return a string from TestMethod does the response passed to the success function contain the string?

Comment: @Calum - No. If, in my success function, I say "alert(response);," I get the HTML of the actual page. My assumption is that it's because it's giving me the "response" of "Page_Load" and not "TestMethod."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figgured it out!  My app was running in .Net 2.0.  I reconfigured the project to run in 4.0 and now it works.  Flipping hell...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[WebMethod]`

With `[WebMethod, System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]`

You need to explicitly tell the web method to use HTTP GET.

If you don't want to do that you have another option.In the `$.ajax` call simply change `type:'GET'` to `type:'POST'` - that will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the question you were asking, but if you are making JSON calls to server side methods that reside in a regular web forms page, you are taking the "slow road".

I would suggest an `HttpHandler`. Unlike your standard web form. there is no page lifecycle (so it is blazing fast) and much cleaner code-separation, as well as reusability.

Add a new item to your project of type "Generic Handler". This will create a new .ashx file. The main method of any class that implements `IHttpHandler` is `ProcessRequest`. So to use the code from your original question:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    Debug.Print("Hello");   
    return;

    //the following code should be used to return json to the ajax method
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
    context.Response.Write(json);
}
```

Change the url in your AJAX call and that should do it. The JavaScript would look like this , where *RunTestMethod.ashx* is the name of the IHttpHandler you just created:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', //change this to POST if you want to pass a json object to the server side method (works in unison with the `dataType` property)
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'Handlers/RunTestMethod.ashx',
    async: true, //notice I set async to true so your page does not "freeze" while the ajax call is being made
    dataType: "json", //if needed, this property allows you to receive json back from the server side method (works in unison with the `type` property)
    success: function (response) {
    alert("SUCCESS");
    }
});
```

Another small point to consider, if you need access to the Session object from within the Handler code itself, make sure to inherit from the `IRequiresSessionState` interface:

```
public class GetFileHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
```